# How to get JacksonXML to de-serialize embedded objects

Tags: jackson, jersey-2.0, jackson-databind

I am writing a REST interface using **Jersey** and have configured it to use JacksonXML to do the JSON<->POJO conversions.  I have a set of classes like this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class JsonPo {
    public Long id;
    public String type;
    public Boolean committed;
    public String owner;
  // ...
```

Which is referenced in my main class like this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class JsonPoReq {
    public Long id;                 
    public String pathstring;      
    public int firstrecord;         
    public JsonPo obj;    
  // ...
```

And the REST resource of course looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("path")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response byPath(JsonPoReq req) {
   // ...
```

The serialization (POJO->JSON) works fine.  The properties in the **JsonPo** object get serialized in a JSON object as you would expect.

The reverse doesn't work.  Even if I feed the serialized string back.  What happens is the **obj** property is always set to **null**.

EDIT: As requested the following is what the JSON string looks like:

```
{
  "id" : 2,
  "pathstring" : "/a/b/c",
  "firstrecord" : 0,
  "obj" : {
    "id" : 2,
    "type" : "ProtoObject",
    "committed" : false,
    "owner" : "admin"
  }
}
```

I have been going through the [JacksonXML Annotations](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-annotations.html) to see how to fix this but I haven't been able to come up with anything.   Is there some other step I am supposed to take?

**UPDATE**:  Problem was not real.   Some application code was being invoked that I didn't notice was clearing the object.

Comment: Do you have a `setObj(JsonPo)` method?

Comment: @peeskillet No -- since the object is public I didn't think I needed one.  Do I?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that. I'm not sure. I've never used public properties except for demos, and even then I only used primitives. Why don't you try and see what happens

Comment: @peeskillet I added    public JsonPo getObj() { return obj; }
    public void setObj(JsonPo value) { obj = value; } but no joy.  I thought you were on to something but I will have to keep poking.

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for your help I got the problem solved.   It turned out that I had some code at the application layer that was setting the **obj** property to null and I wasn't aware it was doing that.  However by the time I had discovered this I had changed my REST app to use MOXy rather than Jackson (and the problem was still there of course!) so I am assuming that the JacksonXML version was working all along.  I am thinking of deleting this posting because the problem it posed was not real.